# Uncertainty of estimates from SVD

Tags: standard-error, error, svd, uncertainty, matrix-decomposition

I have a vector of values $\vec d$ that have each been measured with known uncertainty $\vec \sigma$.

With an equation

$$ \mathbf{A} \vec x = \vec d$$

where both $\mathbf{A}$ and $\vec d$ have been divided by $\vec \sigma$, I can estimate $\vec x$ using the singular value decomposition (SVD) via

$$ \mathbf{A} = \mathbf{U} \boldsymbol{\Sigma} \mathbf{V}^T $$
$$ \vec x = \mathbf{V} \boldsymbol{\Sigma}^{-1} \mathbf{U}^T \vec{d}. $$

What is the uncertainty on each component of $\vec x$?

Comment: You have estimated $x$ with the ordinary least squares solution.  Why not, then, use the standard estimates of its variance-covariance matrix?

Comment: @whuber How can I do that?